# JavaScript Moving transition without the use of CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I'm using a small script to follow the cursor with a `div` element.
This script makes the element strictly follow the cursor.
What I'm trying to do is to add some kind of duration to the process of "following" the cursor. I tried CSS transitions but the animation always ended up breaking. Can somebody please help me with this?

Let's say mouse is somewhere, and then it changes position by around 100px. I want to specify the duration like if i was using CSS... But the thing is that I can not use any transitions but only some javascript magic instead...

```js
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {

  var curX = e.clientX;
  var curY = e.clientY;

  document.querySelector('mouse').style.left = curX - 10 + 'px';
  document.querySelector('mouse').style.top = curY - 10 + 'px';

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
mouse {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <mouse></mouse>
</body>
```

I was wondering how to add a transition without using the CSS but I'm not the most advanced when it comes to JavaScript.

[edit] : I don't wanna use `window.setTimeout`.

[edit 2] : I wanted to use `transition: 0.1s;` but as I said it broke the effect when user moved the mouse too quickly.

Comment: Hi there, does this look like what you are trying to do? https://codepen.io/matthewpageuk/pen/ZwYEKp  the ball follows the mouse?

Comment: Yes exactly! But i'm wondering... your code executes only on mouse move... and when the mouse stops mooving... then I have a problem... Thanks anyway!

Comment: So if the mouse is not triggering events, and you don't want CSS transitions nor `setTimeout`, then how do you imagine doing the animation?

Comment: Then the animation would have to run constantly but it's not a good idea...

Comment: Have you looked at window.requestAnimationFrame() , it was kind of meant for this type of thing. You basically want to do what you do in the mousemove block but 30 or 60 times per second.

Comment: @AleksanderCiecierski I've updated the code to show how it works https://codepen.io/matthewpageuk/pen/ZwYEKp , if you want to get fancy you could stop the animation when the ball finds the mouse..

Comment: My eyes are tearing with the beauty of the phenomenon which is animation... Would you want to make an actual answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a whole bunch of ways to do this, as you can see in the other answers, each with its own "feel". I'm just adding one more, where the dot approaches the cursor by a percentage of the remaining distance.

```js
let curX = 0, curY = 0, elemX = null, elemY = null;
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  curX = e.clientX;
  curY = e.clientY;
  if (elemX === null) [ elemX, elemY ] = [ curX, curY ];
});

let amt = 0.1; // higher amount = faster tracking = quicker transition
let elem = document.querySelector('mouse');
let frame = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  elemX = (elemX * (1 - amt)) + (curX * amt);
  elemY = (elemY * (1 - amt)) + (curY * amt);
  elem.style.left = `${elemX}px`;
  elem.style.top = `${elemY}px`;
};
frame();
```

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  background: #333;
  left: 0; top: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
mouse {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px; margin-left: -10px;
  width: 20px; margin-top: -10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <mouse></mouse>
</body>
```

Comment: Good solution if you ask me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout()` function, to introduce a delay:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  var delay=250 //Setting the delay to quarter of a second
  setTimeout(()=>{
      var curX = e.clientX;
      var curY = e.clientY;
      
      document.querySelector('mouse').style.left = curX - 10 + 'px';
      document.querySelector('mouse').style.top = curY - 10 + 'px';
  },delay)

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
mouse {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <mouse></mouse>
</body>
```

Or, to avoid trailing, use an interval and move the cursor to the correct direction (change `ratio` to set the speed ratio):

```js
var curX,curY
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    curX = e.clientX;
    curY = e.clientY;

});
setInterval(()=>{
    var ratio=5
    var x=document.querySelector('mouse').offsetLeft+10
    var y=document.querySelector('mouse').offsetTop+10
    document.querySelector('mouse').style.left=((curX-x)/ratio)+x-10+"px"
    document.querySelector('mouse').style.top=((curY-y)/ratio)+y-10+"px"
},16)
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
mouse {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <mouse></mouse>
</body>
```